# annotating a video in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, video, annotations

I have a simple wp7 app where, among other things, i can capture/preview/download/upload videos. Nothing fancy, just basic functionality.
What i want to do now is to add some annotations (text over the video) to the video that is stored (as mp4) in the isolated storage. After annotating it i would again save the annotated video to the isolated storage.

The annotating should be done programmatically - for example when my app's status changes, some predefined text annotation will be added to the current video. Basically i would like to have something like this if possible:

```
public mp4Video annotateVideo(mp4Video video, string text){
    ...
    //code that sets the annotation
    ...
    return annotatedVideo;
}
```

Does anyone know how might i do that? Examples would be great.

Comment: What is an `mp4Video` object? What do you mean by "adding text to the video"? Is this like subtitles? What have you tried?

Comment: @MattLacey 'mp4Video' is not defined, i was just trying to suggest that i was working whit mp4 format, hopefully there is a native class that would be in that place as return type(i dont know what are my options here). By adding text to the video i mean like on youtube, those boxes that pop up with some text/link. My question here is attempt to get directions what to try, because i have no idea how to do this, yet i have been given a task to do it. :)

Comment: nothing, except searching the internet for examples how could i do it, but couldn't find any. Does that mean that i shouldn't have posted this question? I tried to present "a specific programming problem" and i thought that this one falls into a category of "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession"...

Comment: All you've done is ask how to do something, not what you've tried or specific issues you're having. You're either talking about directly manipulating the video stream or adding YouTube specific overlays - I'd expect them to be very different tasks. See also http://tinyurl.com/so-hints.